# perl 'require' in begin block

Tags: perl, module, runtime, require

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

BEGIN {
       my $supported = undef;
       *compute_factorial = sub { if (eval { require bignum; bignum->import(); 1;}) {
                                    my $num       = shift;
                                    my $factorial = 1;
                                    foreach my $num (1..$num) {
                                        $factorial *= $num; 
                                    }
                                    return $factorial;
                                  }  else {
                                       undef;
                                     } };
       };

my $f = compute_factorial(25);
say $f;
```

I'm just testing something, not really a production code...
I do have `bignum` pragma on my machine (perfectly loadable using `use`), I was wondering why `require` doesn't work as it should be (I'm getting exponential numbers rather then "big numbers") in this case?

Thanks,

Comment: what makes you think require doesn't load it in this case?

Comment: I still get exponential numbers when $num is >= 19 on my 32bit machine

Comment: I meant it loads it, but doesnt import what it needs I guess..since I dont get undef value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bignum's import needs to be called before compilation of the code it is intended to effect, or it doesn't work.  Here, the BEGIN makes it called before your actual compute_factorial call, but *not* before the critical `my $factorial = 1;` is compiled.

A better approach for cases like this is just to directly use Math::Big*:

```
if (eval { require Math::BigInt }) {
    my $num = shift;
    my $factorial = Math::BigInt->new(1);
    foreach my $num (1..$num) {
        $factorial *= $num;                            
    }
    return $factorial;
} else {
    undef;
}
```

Comment: I like this method. Just to clarify, the [`bignum`](https://metacpan.org/module/bignum#DESCRIPTION) pragma automagically upgrades numbers to [`Math::Big*`](https://metacpan.org/release/Math-BigInt) objects. So if the automagic is causing problems, ysth is suggesting to simply make these objects manually.

Comment: dont really get it, isnt using 'use' instead of 'require' makes it load the module at compile time? how does this works in this case? I used 'require' to make sure that the module is available at RUNTIME.

Comment: but I think I should bang my head against the wall first...BEGIN is a compile the directive, so this block will run at compile time, including the 'require' in it?

Comment: @soulSurfer2010, The above code was buggy. Fixed s/use/require/. Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. thanks! btw, there is no sane reason to use 'use' in an eval block, right?

Comment: the whole thing is a little fishy, though; Math::BigInt and bignum are core modules (though a few years ago Math::BigInt was adopted by a new maintainer and got tons of bug fixes, which a very old perl won't have)

Answer (score 3):

```
BEGIN {
   require bignum;
   import bignum;
   my $x = 1;
}
```

and

```
require bignum;
import bignum;
my $x = 1;
```

are the same because `require` and `import` are executed after `my $x = 1;` is already compiled, so bignum never has a chance to make `my $x = 1;` compile into `my $x = Math::BigInt->new(1);`. Keep in mind that

```
use bignum;
my $x = 1;
```

is actually

```
BEGIN {
   require bignum;
   import bignum;
}
my $x = 1;
```

and not

```
BEGIN {
   require bignum;
   import bignum;
   my $x = 1;
}
```

The solution would be

```
BEGIN {
   my $sub;
   if (eval { require bignum; }) {
      $sub = eval(<<'__EOI__') or die $@;
         use bignum;
         sub {
            my ($num) = @_;
            my $factorial = 1;
            $factorial *= $_ for 2..$num;
            return $factorial;
         }
__EOI__
   } else {
      $sub = sub { croak "Unsupported" };
   }

   *factorial = $sub;
}
```

Of course, since you can simply eliminate the pragma, that would be best.

```
BEGIN {
   my $sub;
   if (eval { require Math::BigInt; }) {
      require Math::BigInt;
      $sub = sub {
         my ($num) = @_;
         my $factorial = Math::BigInt->new(1);
         $factorial *= $_ for 2..$num;
         return $factorial;
      };
   } else {
      $sub = sub { croak "Unsupported" };
   }

   *factorial = $sub;
}
```

Comment: In both cases, you only need the `BEGIN` if you want to be able to do `factorial 20` instead of just `factorial(20)`.

Answer (score 0):

As many other pragmas, in newer versions of Perl `bignum` is only active in scope where you imported it. However, unlike many it also does some funky messing up with upgrading scoped numbers that doesn't quite work with just `require`. You will have to break check for its existence and use in two different files to isolate scope and still let it do its magic.

big.pl

```
if (eval { require bignum; 1 }) {
    require big_loader;
}

print big_loader::big_num_returner();

print "still ok\n";
```

big_loader.pm

```
package big_loader;
use bignum;

sub big_num_returner {
    return 2**512
}

1;
```

Comment: doesn't help; it still isn't called soon enough.  in any case, you are incorrect.  import expects the extra level of scope (think about `use Foo` => `BEGIN { require Foo; import Foo }`); the pragma hint is set for the entire remainder of the OP's BEGIN block, but only at runtime of that block.

Comment: @ysth, hm, indeed. Looking at source it is a little trickier. See updated answer.